# OpenGL ES Camera reverse itself (bad calculation with spherical coordinates ?)

Tags: opengl-es

I'm coding a camera inside a skybox, the camera is supposed to rotate arround a model (the model is in the middle down (0;0;-1) of the skybox although it may change in the future)

I have 2 angles + 1 distance :

```
float theta = m_ry; //m_ry & m_rz are variables incrementing themselves when user
float phi = m_rz;   //click a button to rotate the camera
float dist = m_tra  //m_tra is the distance from camera to the model
```

3 vectors :

```
glm::vec3 eye, center, up;
up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
center = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
```

here's how I set my camera coordinates :

```
eye.x = dist * cosf(theta) * cosf(phi);
eye.y = dist * cosf(theta) * sinf(phi);
eye.z = dist * sinf(theta) - 1; // -1 so the camera is in front of my model
```

then I just make a :

```
modelviewMatrix = glm::lookAt(eye, center, up);
glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(modelviewMatrix);
```

Rotation are working great at the begining, but when I come to an m_rz angle > PI/2, x become negative, and the view is totally reversed :

```
|======|                        |======|
|      |                        |      |
|--*   |       becomes =>       |   *--|
|      |    "--*" is my model   |      |
|______|                        |______|
```

Any idea so the 360°rotation works good without no reverse ?

Answer (score 0):

By these formulas, you are defining your Z axes as inclination reference, and azimuth to be an angle in xy plane. Is that really what you want. In GL, "default" up vector is +y-axis, and you also defined it as your up vector for lookAt function, so you might want to consider switching equations for y and z coordinates of eye.

That way, phy would be an angle for rotation around object, and by changing theta you would move your eye below or above object. Think of changing theta like this. You are in space above USA. By increasing theta towards pi/2, you would change your position towards North Pole. If you go above pi/2 and more, you would found yourself somewhere above Russia. While you were above USA, Europe was to your right. Now it's to your left. It's just laws of physics :)

That is why your object "becomes reversed". It's normal, just not when you move around it, but when you cross poles. So, try these equations. (I'm not sure if yours are bad, although they look somehow inverse, maybe they are OK, just switch axes).

```
eye.x = dist * sin(theta) * cosf(phi);
eye.y = dist * cosf(theta) - 1;
eye.z = dist * sinf(theta) * cosf(phi);
```

Comment: It's not working with your coordinates :s
I found a way to solve my problem, putting the up vector to (0;0;1) instead of (0;1;0)

Comment: Hmm, that should be same as switching those equations. Glad you found solution, thou.